# How can I change ReactJS Project (folder) name?

Tags: reactjs

How can I change ReactJS project(folder) name, simply rename the folder name from `routing`(folder) to  `react-routing-example`(folder).

I found few renaming questions in this stack overflow but they are related to React-native but not Reactjs.

Edit 1: while creating a reactjs app.. i followed the following command:

`npm create-react-app router`

Here `router` is my folder name.Now I want to change that name to `react-router-example`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the question but, if you want to change the name of any folder in your project just rename it and make sure you rename all your imports paths in every component this folder is called.

Comment: I have edited my question. I want to change the total app folder name. @VitoMadio

Comment: 'mv router react-routing-example'

Comment: 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command @static_null

Answer (score 66):

just rename the project folder then open package.json and change the project name  to react-router-example

Comment: you can change the folder name by "mv" command but for package.json you should open it in your code editor and change it! I don't know if there is a command to do this!

Comment: I have an error "Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Projects\Next Projects\projectname\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next' It doesnt work.

Answer (score 18):

you can first rename the folder from router to react-routing-example.
then change the name from in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

Or for simplicity use the search tab in vscode to replace the name at once.

Here you can see - [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNYGJ.png)

Answer (score 3):

I also used *sudo mv previous-name-of-the-app new-app-name* and it worked. I had to manually change the name inside the package.json file and then run localhost from the beginning to see the change.